# Retrofit 2.4.0 Converts all parameter to zero

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2

FROM POSTMAN http://localhost:5757/api/public/addcart/56/12/4 this works great.

But when using Retroift i get this.

http://10.0.2.2:5757/api/public/addcart/3/4/24

endpoint changes to

http://10.0.2.2:5757/api/public/addcart/0/0/0

In my table column i get value of Zero for each column

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("addcart/user_id/men_wears_id/quantity")
    Call<CartResponse> addToCart(
            @Field("user_id") int user_id,
            @Field("men_wears_id") int men_wears_id,
            @Field("quantity") int quantity
    );
```

Thank you.

Comment: you have to use `@Path` not `@Field`

Answer (score 0):

Make your API type from `@POST` to `@GET` and use @Path parameters instead of @Field like below *(@FormUrlEncoded is required with POST methods only)*:

```
@GET("addcart/user_id/men_wears_id/quantity")
Call<CartResponse> addToCart( @Path("user_id") int user_id, 
     @Path("men_wears_id") int men_wears_id, 
     @Path("quantity") int quantity );
```

Comment: Am performing a post operation.

Comment: From URLs in question looks like a get operation to me instead of Post

Comment: Thank you, i have changed it to POST and its working.